# Error in connecting VS2012 with Sonarqube server via VSSonarExtension2012

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I was trying to connect VS2012 with Sonarqube via VSSonarExtension2012 it gives an error of 'Wrong Credentials' .
While it gets connected successfully with VS2015 via SonarLint with same credentials .
What could be the reason for different behavior in VS2012 ?
Thanks in Advance!